# Getting NHibernate.Mappings.Attributes to work Options

Tags: nhibernate, attributes, nhibernate-mapping

I'm using v2.1 of NHibernate.dll and NHibernate.Mappings.Attributes v2.1 in a project.

When I run the code further below, I get the following exception, and will be grateful for any pointers. On the same project, if I remove the attributes and use xml mapping files, it works fine.

```
NHibernate.MappingException was unhandled 
Message="Could not compile the mapping document: 
DomainModel.hbm.xml" 
Source="NHibernate" 

InnerException: System.NullReferenceException 
Message="Object reference not set to an instance of an object." 
Source="NHibernate" 
StackTrace: 
at NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.ClassBinder.BindClass 
(XmlNode node, PersistentClass model) 
at NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.RootClassBinder.Bind 
(XmlNode node, HbmClass classSchema) 
at NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.MappingRootBinder.AddRootClasses(XmlNode 
parentNode) 
at NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.MappingRootBinder.Bind(XmlNode node) 
at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddValidatedDocument(NamedXmlDocument doc) 
InnerException:
```

I have a contact class as follows (Domain class has just one method, no properties):

```
[NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Class] 
public class Contact : DomainClass 
{ 
    [NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Id(Name = "Id")] 
    [NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Generator(1, Class ="Identity")] 
    public virtual int ID { get; set; } 

    [NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Property] 
    public virtual string Name { get; set; } 

    [NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Property] 
    public virtual string Town { get; set; } 
}
```

and session code as follows:

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration(); 
cfg.Configure(); 
cfg.AddInputStream(NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.HbmSerializer.Default.Serialize( 
typeof(Contact).Assembly), "DomainModel.hbm.xml"); 
_sessionFactory=cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml file is:

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2"> 
<session-factory> 
<property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect</property> 
<property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</ 
property> 
<property name="connection.connection_string">Server=SERVER 
\EXPRESS2008;Initial Catalog=Contacts;Integrated Security=True</property> 
<property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFac­    tory, NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu</property> 
</session-factory> 
</hibernate-configuration>
```

---

Stuart,

As I understand it,"DomainModel.hbm.xml" is the file NHibernate.Mappings.Attributes should create - the exception happens before the file is created (it's not in the output directory) and so unfortunately I can't post it.

Comment: Could you post the DomainModel.hbm.xml file? The error message implies that something is missing from the XML mapping file when it is generated by the attributes code.

Answer (score 2):

Stuart,

Thanks again for your response.

Managed to get it to work using:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream()) 
{ 
HbmSerializer.Default.HbmNamespace = "NSpace.DomainLayer.Entities"; 
HbmSerializer.Default.HbmAssembly = "NSpace"; 
HbmSerializer.Default.Serialize(stream, 
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()); 
stream.Position = 0; 
Configuration cfg = new Configuration(); 
cfg.Configure(); 
cfg.AddInputStream(stream); 
_sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory(); 
}
```

and specifying table names in class attributes (my oversight as these were different from class names!).

Not sure why we need to specify Namespace separately, as I assumed NHibernate could work out the types to serialize from the assembly.

Hope above helps anyone experiencing similar issue, although my impression is few people are using NHibernate.Mappings.Attributes. The documentation seems to be seriously lacking.

Comment: Thanks very much for this - how did you figure it out?! This attributes support seems quite poorly designed and implemented to me; why do the attributes need to be given position integers? why does it generate XML instead of just programatically configuring the mappings directly? And why does it leave out information it can easily discover automatically?

Answer (score 1):

If you have not solved your problem yet, try this

```
[NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Class(Table="youtable",NameType=typeof(Contact ))] 
public class Contact : DomainClass 
{ 
    [NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Id(Name = "Id")] 
    [NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Generator(1, Class ="Identity")] 
    public virtual int ID { get; set; } 

    [NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Property(Name="Name")] 
    public virtual string Name { get; set; } 

    [NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Property(Name="Town")] 
    public virtual string Town { get; set; } 
}
```

I'm using like this and it works fine .....

Comment: That helped.  I did need Class = "identity", at least in my hibernate 4.0.3

Answer (score 1):

For a while, NHMA didn't auto detect classes names because they are now optional in NHibernate (in some scenarios, you would use entity-name instead).
The most recent version however restores the auto-detect behavior with a setting to turn that off if needed.

The attributes must be manually ordered because .NET doesn't guarantee it when compiling (unlike Java).

The end goal of NHMA is to faithfully duplicate the way you write the XML version; so if you have:

```
<something>
  <innerData/>
</something>
```

The NHMA version will be:

```
[Something]
  [InnerData(2)]
```

NHMA tries to be smart about deducing certain values (like names), but it will only do so if the value is required.

It also provide helpers like `NameType=typeof(XXX)` to benefit from intellisense, compile time verification and refactoring.

More details in the documentation:
http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-attributes

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use **hbm.xml** file you will set your configuration class like this:

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.Configure();
// Add class mappings to configuration object
cfg.AddAssembly(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
ISessionFactory sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
```

Whenever you use Nhibernate.Mapping.Attributes like classe you will use:

For example you have use Mapping.attributes in Product Class

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.Configure();

// Add class mappings attributes to configuration object
cfg.AddInputStream(HbmSerializer.Default.Serialize(typeof(Model.Product);
ISessionFactory sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
```

Answer (score 0):

I must say that NHibnerate.Mapping.Atributes component was poorly written.
The code below will lead to a generation of malformed mapping xml

```
[Class()]
public class Bar{}
```

Meanwhile, the code below is fine:

```
[Class(Name="Bar")]
public class Bar{}
```

Further more, if you place [Generator] attribute after [Id] attribute, then the information about generator will not be included in the xml, but place [Generator] before [Id] will do the jobs.

The 3.0 is under working and I hope that these "nasty" bugs will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

As indicted above, you have to specify the class' Name since version 2...
I have posted an article on how to work around this by deriving the HbmWriter: http://blog.hopla.org/2009/12/fix-for-nhibernate-mapping-attributes-2-1/

Answer (score 0):

Almost copy of **mitjast**'s answer, with minor fixes and formatting:

```
[Class(NameType = typeof(DomainClass))]
public class DomainClass
{
    [NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Generator(Class = "guid")]
    [NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Id(Name = "DomainID")]
    public virtual Guid DomainID { get; set; }
    [NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Property]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

That definition helped me get through all exceptions and generate valid hbm mapping.
As **Mr Cold** mentioned, the order of **Generator** and **Id** attributes does matter.
But in my case it was discovered that while for one class **Id** should go first to be actually mentioned within hbm, for another class the first attribute should be **Generator**. When I change the order of these attributes in one class so that both classes have equal order, the hbm for one of them becomes wrong...
The situation did not change after the release of *NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes-for-NHibernate-3.0.0.Alpha2*.
Presence of such quirky things looks enough for me to switch to another solution unfortunately...